# "Person ID" and "Throttled Member Count"

Tags: linkedin-api

My app is getting

> Throttle limit for calls to this resource is reached.

but when I go to the "Usage & Limits" section all I see is

[image]

Since it is all green and current is << Maximum, is the problem that "1" under Throttled Member Count?

It is unclear to me how to work around this, what are my options?